# Is it possible to pack native binaries (built for ARM) of Android app with UPX?

Tags: android, android-ndk, upx

The latest Windows UPX version 3.09w throws UnknownExecutableFormatException, so it apparently doesn't support Android .so binaries for ARM. Are there any UPX forks for Android?

Comment: I thought UPX only worked with end executables, not libraries..

Comment: @user2246674: it works with `.dll` and `.so` binaries for x86.